# How to Link Layers Between Photoshop Documents?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

So I had a look around and couldn't find anything that clarifies this.
I have a logo in a PSD that it basically two letters with custom extra bits.

What is the best way to approach linking these layers/groups into a new PSD document?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2/5/2024**

Photoshop now supports linking and embedding through the `File > Place linked...` and `File > Place Embedded...` functions.

**Original Answer**

Save the document as a copy as is with layers so as to not lose your work.

Create a new PSD Document or open the document you wish to place your logo into, then go to file> Place and choose the location that you have saved your logo file, it should now be linked as a smart object and double clicking on it in the layers panel will bring up the original with layers.

Alternatively Create your new PSD document then go back to your original document and click window>arrange>float in window.

Then holding Ctrl select each element in the layers panel (layer, group etc.) that you wish to place into the new document and then hold shift and drag from the layers panel directly onto the new document below.

Comment: Photoshop unfortunately does not have a "live" link option, where editing one PSD affects a second PSD where it is placed. Instead, placing one PSD inside another will make it a Smart Object, which can be edited through double-clicking, as James says. This may not be the kind of "linked" you're looking for (from the video world, if I insert a PSD into Premiere, I can then edit that PSD, and it is edited in Premiere, because it's pulling from the file "live" and not saving a copy) - however, this is the only "linking" available in Photoshop.